# array_rand - how can I get more values than array has?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to get more random values than array has using array_rand. Is there any way to do it?

```
    $amount = 6;

    $numbers = array(
       "10",
       "20", 
       "30"
    );

    array_rand($numbers, $amount);
```

I can only get 3 values, because array has only 3 values. But what if I want to get like 6 values (of course if $qty > array has, will repeat but theres no problem)

Comment: Please check documentation for array_rand: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php -  Trying to pick more elements than there are in the array will result in an E_WARNING level error, and NULL will be returned.

Comment: Doesn't make sense....What would be the expected output? Show us an example

Comment: If the array only have 3 values, what other values would you expect? `array_values()` does exactly what the manual says and is designed to do. It gives you a random key from an array.

Comment: For a quickie, I guess you could run `array_rand` twice and combine them with `array_merge` Like: `array_merge(array_rand($numbers, 3),array_rand($numbers, 3));`

Comment: @B001ᛦ Currently I do $random = array_rand($numbers, 6) and I do foreach to get all values from array_rand, but because the value I want is 2x bigger than array has, it gives me error in 3 options "Undefined offset"

Comment: Why not just duplicate the values and be done with it?

Comment: @IsThisJavascript seems to be the only one option, the problem is its a big algorithm and the amount of numbers I want to get is a variable so wont work well

Comment: @Script47 Im going to try it

Comment: `the amount of numbers I want to get is a variable` Not sure what you mean here. In the example provided you show you want a random array twice the size of the original, do you just want one value from the randomized array?

Comment: @IsThisJavascript the OP wants `array_rand` to pull out more random values than they are available in the original array, even if they are duplicates. So array count is 3, but they want to run `array_rand` to get 6 randomly selected values from that 3 length array.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript I gonna edit to show you better

Comment: @Script47 Yeah, not sure if you missed what I suggested the OP use and where I took that quote from. His reasoning to avoid using `array_rand` twice then just combine the results just confused me xD

Comment: @GustavoMacedo Where do you pull the 6 from for `$amount = 6;` ? I mean you could just do : `array_merge(array_rand($numbers,  $amount),array_rand($numbers, $amount));` but only if  `$amount` is the correct size? The other method I can suggest is just use the `$amount = count($numbers)` value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a custom solution that is not dependent on the features of array rand:

See it in action:
https://ideone.com/Kimjx4

```
// The quantity you want
$quantity = 6;

// the values to choose from
$numbers = array(
       "10",
       "20", 
       "30"
    );
// get the keys so it will also work with associative arrays
$keys = array_keys($numbers);

// how many elements are there in our source array
$length = count($keys);    

// where we store our result
$result = [];

// iterate for x quantity
for($c=0;$c < $quantity; $c++) {
   // add random result from source to result array.
   $result[] = $numbers[$keys[rand(0, $length-1)]];
}

var_dump($result);
```

if you want it as a function that also handles associative keys
https://ideone.com/SqTrKg

```
function getRandomResults(array $source, $quantity) {
    $keys = array_keys($source);

    // how many elements are there in our source array
    $length = count($keys);    

    // where we store our result
    $result = [];

    // iterate for x quantity
    for($c=0;$c < $quantity; $c++) {
       // add random result from source to result array.
       $result[] = $source[$keys[rand(0, $length-1)]];
    }
    return $result;
}
$res = getRandomResults([
           "10",
           "20", 
           "30"
        ], 6);
var_dump($res);
```

Comment: @GustavoMacedo I updated the function to work with associative arrays as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like also to try))

```
function my_array_rand(array $arr, int $count): array
{
    assert($count > 0);

    if ($count <= count($arr)) {
        return array_rand($arr, $count);
    }

    foreach (range(1, $count) as $index) {
        $res[] = array_rand($arr, 1);
    }

    return $res ?? [];
}


$arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var_dump(my_array_rand($arr, 100));
```